# I wrote a code with instantiate and it copies prefab to the scene. I wanna delete it in a scene, not a prefab. How do I?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Game object b is a meteor that dont kill but shows where will real meteor(a) spawn. Heres the code:

```
 IEnumerator hard()
    {   
        
        while(true)
        {   
            x1 = Random.Range(-10, 10);
            y1 = Random.Range(6, -6);
            x2 = Random.Range(-10, 10);
            y2 = Random.Range(6, -6);
            x3 = Random.Range(-10, 10);
            y3 = Random.Range(6, -6);
            Instantiate(b, new Vector3(x1, y1, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate(b, new Vector3(x2, y2, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate(b, new Vector3(x3, y3, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
            Instantiate(a, new Vector3(x1, y1, 0), Quaternion.identity); 
            Instantiate(a, new Vector3(x2, y2, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate(a, new Vector3(x3, y3, 0), Quaternion.identity);   
        }
    }


    IEnumerator clean()
    {
        Destroy(b, 1);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    }
```

The error message is:

Destroying assets is not permitted to avoid data loss.
If you really want to remove an asset use DestroyImmediate (theObject, true);

I dont need do destroy asset, only destroy gameobject in scene, how??

I tried to use DestroyImmediate() even though I dont need it, but it still says that no permission.

Comment: Not sure, but probably creating a gameobject variable in which the object is instantiated and then destroying the gameobject variable should work. Try this: `Gameobject gameObjectB = Instantiate(b, new Vector3(x1, y1, 0), Quaternion.identity);` and then `Destroy(gameObjectB, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

[Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) returns the reference to the spawned GameObject. You need to save it in a temp variable and destroy that object at the appropriate time.

```csharp
 IEnumerator hard()
{   
    while(true)
    {   
        x1 = Random.Range(-10, 10);
        y1 = Random.Range(6, -6);
        x2 = Random.Range(-10, 10);
        y2 = Random.Range(6, -6);
        x3 = Random.Range(-10, 10);
        y3 = Random.Range(6, -6);
        GameObject temp1 = Instantiate(b, new Vector3(x1, y1, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        GameObject temp2 = Instantiate(b, new Vector3(x2, y2, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        GameObject temp3 = Instantiate(b, new Vector3(x3, y3, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        Destroy(temp1);
        Destroy(temp2);
        Destroy(temp3);
        Instantiate(a, new Vector3(x1, y1, 0), Quaternion.identity); 
        Instantiate(a, new Vector3(x2, y2, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate(a, new Vector3(x3, y3, 0), Quaternion.identity);   
    }
}
```

Alternatively, since you mention that the coruoutine can be stopped before the cleanup you can give your prefabs Tags and use the [GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) function to find them in your scene when you do the cleanup.

```csharp
void Clean(){
  GameObject[] trash = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Trash");
  foreach(GameObject item in trash){
    Destroy(item);
  }
}
```

In this example when you call the `Clean` function all objects in your scene with the "Trash" tag will be removed.

Comment: You might not get it right. When I change game mode from hard() to normal() or easy(), I use function StopAllCoroutines() in order not to get more than 3 instatiates a time, so this Destroy(temp) wont work. Anyways, thanks for your help, Ima try solve this problem myself <3

Comment: @GoTouchGrass I've updated my answer, which doesn't rely on the Coroutine being completed.

Comment: Thats nice! But when I start game at easy mode(1 instantiate) like 2 things spawn instantly and than its okay. But when I added this function to every changing-mode function, If I change mode, StopAllCoroutines() wont work and it is like 6 instatiates one after another

Comment: @GoTouchGrass it's not very clear what you mean for someone that isn't familiar with your game. It sounds like something is up with the way you switch difficulties. You might want to ask a new question regarding that.